# jQuery close dialog when ajax call end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that inside makes an ajax call. At first I open the dialog with the message 'Loading' inside. Can i access the dialog again after the call and close it ?. Below is my code:

```
   function CallAction(){
    $("#example").dialog({modal: true});
    //do some ajax call
    //how to close it after call ends ?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, close it in the AJAX `success` or `done` call:

```
success: function(data) {
    //do stuff
    $("#example").dialog('close');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the complete callback of the ajax request, then use the [close](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close) method to close the dialog

```
$.ajax({....}).always(function(){
    $("#example").dialog('close');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to close the dialog in any case(success or error), use *complete*:

```
complete: function() {
   $("#example").dialog({modal: true});
}
```